# Why is UIPickerView didSelectRow method crashing?

Tags: iphone, methods, uipickerview

I'm a noob to iphone development(2nd day in xcode) and I am developing a beginners app that uses a UIPickerView with three components.  I have using this [tutorial](http://joshhighland.com/blog/2009/09/17/uipickerview-spinning-multiple-components/), but some reason when I change the position of either of my components my app crashes.  I have no clue what could be going on and the only thing i have to go on is "Thread: Stopped after step" at the particular line that crashes the app.  Any help resolving this is greatly appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component{

NSInteger selectedTransaction = [pickerView  selectedRowInComponent:0]; //App crashes here
NSInteger selectedCoinOrScrap = [pickerView  selectedRowInComponent:1];
NSInteger selectedCurrency = [pickerView  selectedRowInComponent:2];


        if(selectedTransaction==2||selectedTransaction==3){
            arrayWhichMetal=[[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:arrayGoldScrapType];
            [pickerView  reloadComponent:1]; 
            if (selectedCoinOrScrap==0) {

            }else if(selectedCoinOrScrap==1){

            }
}
```

Comment: Please post more details...

Comment: Are you sure you're not stopping at a breakpoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you may need to clean your project.